# How to change default route in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net web api. I am trying to set the default route for my project in global.asax file like,

```
localhost:45678/api/Products
```

But i didnt find any format similar to asp.net mvc route model like

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

It always redirects me to Home page(HomeController). please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by "It always redirects me to Home page".  Do you mean that when you navigate to localhost:45678/api/Products it redirects you or when you run your project from Visual Studio the first page you land on is your home page?

Comment: when i run my project it redirects me to Home page.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: How can I do the same in IIS?

Answer (score 12):

Check your your `RouteConfig` class in your `App_Start` folder.  You should see the default route below which you can change.

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**EDIT**

After reading your comments, I think the problem is not with your routes.  I'm not sure why you would *want* to do it, but you just need to specify the Start URL for your project. Right click your web project - click **Properties** - click the **Web** tab - under Start Action select **Start URL** and enter `http://localhost:45678/api/Products` in the box.  Save your project and run again.  It should start at the new location.

Comment: I have tried with this code in global.asax `routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Products", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );` but it still redirects to home page. I didnt find RouteConfig class in App_Start

Comment: Do you have a controller called "ProductsController" inheriting from ApiController and do you have a "public IEnumerable<string> Get()" method on this controller?

Comment: yes sir i have `public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return products;
        }` in productscontroller:ApiController

Comment: Sorry, I'm at loss. Just to clarify though, by default your GetAll() method will return a JSON array of Product objects, not a web page.  Navigating to localhost:45678/api/Products directly from your browser may do something unexpected.  If you compose a GET request to that address with Fiddler, you should see a JSON array in the response body (if it's working as expected, of course!).

Comment: i have used `localhost:56789/api/products` i got all products table/class records in JSON Array format in response.

Answer (score 4):

The issue might be the common mistake that nearly lots of people get into.

The fact here is that the all routes get collected under `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes` collection regardless of the framework you use. So, if you put the ASP.NET MVC default route before the ASP.NET Web API route, the ASP.NET Web API route will never be scanned because the MVC route will be a match.

I am assuming this is the case here by looking at what you've provided so far. If that's not the case, upload the full solution out there somewhere and people can have a full look.

Comment: so may i know what to do for it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually if we are in the position to set the default route in properties->web->start location. then what is the need of route tables, custom routes,RegisterRoutes in global.asax file. I tried for this way

at first it seems like,

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default Api",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now i want to make `localhost:xxxx/api/products` as default route for my web api then,

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Products/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But the results of no use.

Comment: Could you improve your question instead of posting an update as answer? (SE doesn't work as a forum) Thanks

Comment: Leandro is right, this should be edited in to the original question. Recommending deletion.

Answer (score 1):

While developing in Visiual Studio, you can set it by expand the **Properties** folder of the project. Then open ***launchSettings.json*** file and look for **"launchUrl"** property in this file

You can change the default launch route for the profile you are working on.

> "launchUrl" : "api/products"

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: My answer is the same as Kevin's]

Are you saying that when you run the project from Visual Studio, it opens a browser to the project home page?

The Web API project template contains an MVC controller plus a Web API controller.

The URI "http://localhost:xxxx/" goes the MVC controller, while "http://localhost:xxx/api/products" goes to the API controller.

When you run the project in Visual Studio, it will navigate to "http://localhost:xxxx" by default. In normal operation, a client would request whichever URI it wanted.

You can change the Visual Studio settings under Project Properties / Web / Start Action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have danced around the solution but just missed the mark. Try this:

1. Make sure you are calling GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); in your Global.asax.cs.
2. In `WebApiConfig.Register()` Set the default route as:

   routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/**{Controller}**/{id}",defaults: new { controller = "Products", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
3. In your web project settings make sure you have "Start Url" property set as:

   localhost:45678

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP .NET Core Web API project, whenever you DEBUG the project, it fires up a browser to a predefined URL. This can be configered by right-clicking the project and going to properties and then Debug tab as shown below.
[image]

That said, not sure what the difference is between this and the **launchsettings.json** described in a previous answer above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
Response.Redirect("Products.aspx");
```

to method `index()` in the class `HomeController`.