# How can I change the default route in asp.net web api in IIS 8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Just an update to this question. [How to change default route in asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172212/how-to-change-default-route-in-asp-net-web-api)

I want to do the same in IIS 8, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default route for the web api is typically set in the WebApiConfig.cs.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api